# Make absolutely positioned children not run out of viewport borders

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, position

Imagine we have a horizontal drop-down menu with a structure like this:

```
<ul class="root">
  <li class="root-item">
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  ...
  <li class="root-item">
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

the css is roughly like this:

```
.root-item{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
.submenu{
    position:absolute;
    top:-1000px;
}
.root-item:hover .submenu{
    top:100%;
}
```

The priblem here is: if some (say, the last) .submenu is wide enough, it may go out of the .root borders, and eventually out of the viewport (if the .root's width is 100% of the VP).

What I want is making .submenu-s fit into the .root; meaning that *left* and *right* of .sumbenu won't get negative. But - with **pure css**, just very curious, if it is possible to skip using javascript here. The desired result is like [ribbon menu here](http://darimnastroenie.ru). Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

http://codepen.io/MisterGrumpyPants/pen/IwfDC

Besides some borders and backgrounds to flesh out an appearance, all I added to your CSS is two classes of submenu: one that aligns to the left of its parent item and extends right ("to-right"), while the other aligns to the right and extends left ("to-left").

This is a simple solution that should work if you know which submenus will need to extend left and which can extend right, and you can control the classes of your submenus.

(If you need something more complicated (e.g. you don't want to have to apply "to-right" and "to-left" classes yourself), that will take some more thought.)

**UPDATE**

Here's another pen that utilizes `:nth-child` selectors to determine which way the submenu swings, instead of manually applied "to-right" and "to-left" classnames:

http://codepen.io/MisterGrumpyPants/pen/ovJcH

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

There is one thing, that complicates it all: in case of dynamic menus with the number of items and (especially) submenues size changing, we can't know in advance, to which items _to-right_ and _to-left_ classes should be applied to.

Comment: You can set a max-width to your submenus, then you would be able to know exactly how many of them could extend right, before they have to start extending left. But if what you want is a totally dynamic, unregulated width and behavior based on what that width turns out to be, I think you have to use JavaScript. CSS won't have any way of knowing what you need to know.

Comment: Also -- did you look at the ":nth-child" version? Because that doesn't require to manually apply classes, it just requires that you know how many items will be able to extend right, before they have to start extending left. Might help.

Comment: Sorry fot the late reply. Unfortunately, niether of those will do since in case of a totally dynamic menu we can't know either the number of items or their size.

... javascript seems to be the only option in the end.